# Cannot put PageView into Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I want to put a small PageView into a Column, but I got error **RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#db5f8 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT**. The PageView will hold inconsistent data so I cannot set the height for it. Can anyone help me? This is my code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Data.getProductDetails(id: widget.product.id),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.grey));
          } else {
            List iList = [];
            iList.add(widget.product.mainImg);
            for (ProductImages i in snapshot.data.imgList) {
              iList.add(i.image);
            }
            return CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverAppBar(...),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(...),
                        Row(...),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        brandField(snapshot),
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        categoryField(snapshot),
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        tagsField(snapshot),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        pageIndicator(),
                        Expanded(
                          child: PageView(
                            children: [
                              Container(height: 400, color: Colors.red),
                              Container(height: 600, color: Colors.blue),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `PageView` and other widgets like `ListView` require size constraints from its parents and Column do not provide constraints to its children. So to solve the issue you can wrap you `PageView` inside `Flexible` or `Expanded` like so:

```dart
Column(
  children:[
      Expanded(child:PageView(),),
  ]
)
```

For better understanding of constrains in flutter, read: [Understanding Constrains: Flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: Thank you @Mayank. In my code I tried this method, I wrapped this PageView into an Expanded but the error still there, I think it relates to the SingleChildScrollView outside the Column. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Yup it's probably beacuse of that. I don't know how you plan to layout your widgets, but I do have one suggestion you, you layout seems a bit complex, try to simplify it and you'll find a fix.